# Problem in plugin debuging in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, user-registration, debug

I want to save extra user fields in custom table after user register.

In my plugin I added `user_register` hook and I am checking this code while user register but I cannot find any errors and cannot print the data.

How can I test this code and what if I want to print something here that will reflect on webpage?

I am new to plugin creation please help you good people.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Bonus Point Calculator Plugin
Plugin URI: 
Description: This plugin adds reward points of user.
Version: 1.0
Author: Test (Dev Team)
Author URI: http://www.test.com
Author Email: support@test.com

  Copyright 2019 Test
*/

define('THEMENAME', 'listingpro');
define('BONUSPOINTS_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

add_action('user_register', 'rwdpoint_registration_save', 10, 1);

function rwdpoint_registration_save($user_id) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $username = $user_info->user_login;
    $useremail = $user_info->user_email;
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->insert('wp_userrewardpoints', array(
        'rwuserid ' => $user_id,
        'rwusername' => $username,
        'rwemail' => $useremail,
        'rwrewardpoint' => 10,
        'rwcreateddate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    ) , array(
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d',
        '%s'
    ));
    if ($sql === false) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return $wpdb->get_results($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. Have you read up on how you can test plugins in general? What specific problem is it you're having with your current code?

Comment: Where you have define('user_register ... Do you mean to have, add_action( ... ?

Comment: I want to call rwdpoint_registration_save function after User register, but can't get in to the function with this hook 'user_register'

Comment: Also, what is $query on your last line?

Comment: yes please check i edited the line from define('user_register') to add_action('user_register').... it was my mistake

Comment: it was the $sql actually, My main issue is, I want to call the function  rwdpoint_registration_save after user register

Comment: Developing plugins I found useful to create and use this snippet for debugging blind spots like yours https://gist.github.com/huraji/e7543dbb91240533ce91a7d5a64b43ed.

Answer (score 0):

What I do, when I'm developing a plugin (or theme) on a local WordPress install and I'm feeling lazy, I just use a combination of

```
var_dump($my_variable); 
die; // exit; works too
```

This way I get an idea whats going on and I see when the variable stops being what I expect it to be.

Another thing I sometimes do is I use `error_log( print_r( $my_variable, true ) );` inside functions to push stuff into the error log so that I can review it later.

Unfortunately I haven't worked that much with custom tables so I can't comment on those matters.